# angular-dragular issue with dragular-model

Tags: angularjs, dragula

I am using the angular-dragula lib.

I have created a dragula container and I am using to arrays as two columns/bags for the dragula container.

The problem I am facing is when I drag an element from row 1 and drop into row 2, the next element is getting dropped and not the current element.

I have created a plunkr to show the issue, link :

http://jsfiddle.net/36meLf7r/14/

#### HTML

```
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <div class='wrapper' layout='row'>
    <div id="Planned" class="container md-block" dragula='"tasks-container"' dragula-model="PlannedList">
      <label>Planned</label>
      <div ng-repeat="plannedTask in PlannedList">
        <div class="info-box-content">
          <span class="info-box-text">{{plannedTask.TaskName}}</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="InProgress" class="container md-block" dragula='"tasks-container"' dragula-model="InProgressList">
```

#### Controller

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', [angularDragula(angular)]);

myApp.controller('myCtrl', ['$scope', 'dragulaService', function($scope, dragulaService) {
  $scope.PlannedList = [{
    TaskName: 1
  }, {
    TaskName: 2
  }];
  $scope.InProgressList = [{
    TaskName: 3
  }, {
    TaskName: 4
  }];

  dragulaService.options($scope, 'first-bag', {
    accepts: function(el, target, source, sibling) {
      return true;
    }
  });
}]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the label element `<label>Planned</label>`  from the bags.Because of them multiple child scopes are getting created due to which `dragula` is not able to get the selected children.